# IOS: start navigation controller form a secondary view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have a first view controller and I open my secondview controller in this way:

```
[self presentModalViewController:puntiVendita animated:YES];
```

but when I'm in secondViewController I have a tableView and I want to begin a navigation controller...what can I do to start a navigation controller from seconviewcontroller via code?
thanks

Comment: Better you make this secondViewController as a root view controller of the navigationController...

Comment: means, initialize a new navigationController and set puntiVendita as a root view controller and add it to your current view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:puntiVendita];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Needless to say, if you need pre-iOS 5 support, use `presentModalViewController`.